# (python) list index out of range - with using selenium click event

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

There are 41 category checkbox, 12 are visible and remain are hidden, need to click on show more to show
hidden checkboxes.

this code 
do that::  1-loop >> 2-click on show more if i <=12 >> 3-click on checkbox

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Compu City\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')
time.sleep(10)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

i=0
while i <= 41 :
    if(i <=12):
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > a > span').click()
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label')[i].click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    time.sleep(2)
    i+=1
```

the problem: code works well with 12 checkboxes and then click on show more then click just on the first checkbox NO.13 then get this error

```
D:\python neww>aaa.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59799/devtools/browser/ac2188e0-10e3-493b-9d91-614731f8d135
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python neww\aaa.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label')[i].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i searched a lot about selution what i found that echeckbox not load , but when change .click() with .text

I get all checkbox label names, so how they don't load

[i mage for checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcpuR.png)

Comment: The error basically tells you that the variable 'lst' is not defined. You need to make sure you assign something to that always before running this line. For us to help you, can you show the code of the whole function?

Comment: I added all code in question

Comment: I can't see the line that fails `lst = [item ...]` in your code.

Comment: sorry it was an error from another file I corrected it

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label')[i].click()` this is the line which is causing issue. Seems to be the `i;th element element matching with `.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label` CSS does not exist on the page. Meaning you don't have those many elements matching that CSS.

Comment: so why when change ```.click()``` with ```.text``` i get all elements

Comment: how more than 40 views and  no solution plz help I spend more than one day  and didn't find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main problem with css selectors because there are three structures for html

1-first structure for first 12 check box

2-second one for first checkbox after click show more

3-third one when click on  first checkbox after show more all structure will change and will include all check box

(i didn't use third part because it will make code so long and i want to short the code)

so try this code , after click on checkbox you will need to click clear so i think this code will be useful

```
first_part = 12
while first_part <=12:
    #click on category checkbox
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > span:nth-child({}) > div > label'.format(first_part)).click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(3)
    #clear filter
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > span > div > a').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(3)
    #print text of checkbox category
    print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > span:nth-child({}) > div > label'.format(first_part)).text)
    first_part+=1
second_part = 1
while second_part <= 26:
    #show more
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > a > span').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    time.sleep(2)
    #print text of checkbox category
    print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > div > span:nth-child({}) > div > label'.format(second_part)).text)
    #click on category checkbox
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > div > span:nth-child({}) > div > label'.format(second_part)).click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(3)
    #clear filter
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > span > div > a').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(3)
    second_part+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem with css selectors
try this code

```
i = 5
while i <= 29:
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(3)
    if(i==5):
        cat =driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > div > span:nth-child({}) > div > label'.format(i)).click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        y=11
        while y<=29:
            cat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child({}) > div > label'.format(y)).click()
            y+=1
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            time.sleep(3)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(3)

    i += 1
    print('i: ', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and sweet script that will work.

```
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')
checkCSS = "[class='a-row a-spacing-small filterItem']:nth-of-type(1) .a-checkbox.checkbox.a-spacing-micro"
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, checkCSS)))
departments = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(checkCSS))

for depNum in range(departments):
    print(depNum)
    if depNum == 12:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.a-expander-prompt"))).click()
        time.sleep(1)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, checkCSS)))
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(checkCSS)[depNum].click()
```